# What could cause scrollTop to malfunction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm have been dealing with a weird bug for the last few hours.  Totally losing my mind on this one.  Hopefully it is something simple that I am just overlooking.  Hope someone can help.

Part of the complexity of the page is I am using Twitter Bootstrap with a fixed header and i am trying to use anchor links on the page as well to link to some things in this rather long page.  I actually had this working before I completed some mobile optimizations to the website today then all of a sudden my anchor links stopped working.

What's happening is when i click the anchor links, the page slides up, but no matter what link i click it always stops on the same link.  I checked and all of my href's are properly closed.  I've tried renaming all of the anchors and the targets to something unique just in case there was some naming conflict, but it still does the same thing.  Pretty much stops where the first anchor.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row subnav-module">
 <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><a href="#opt1" class="blue-bubble-btn">option 1</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><a href="#opt2" class="blue-bubble-btn">option 2</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><a href="#opt3" class="blue-bubble-btn">option 3</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><a href="#opt4" class="blue-bubble-btn">option 4</a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then my anchor looks like this:

```
<a name="opt1"></a>
```

And then there is content and divs between each of the anchors.

Here is the javascript i am using:

```
jQuery('.subnav-module a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {

  // grab the anchor link name, the hash
  var href = jQuery.attr(this, 'href');
  var target = jQuery(this.hash);

  target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 150 //offsets for fixed header
    }, 1000, function () { window.location.hash = href; });
    return false;
   }
 }
});
```

I attempted a console.log(scrollTop) after that line and it returned the same number when i clicked each anchor link.  So, i think it is miscalculating the position on the page of these divs.

But, what would cause this script to miscalculate that?

**Other things I've tried:**

- Removed all of the media queries from the stylesheet - didnt help.
- Removed rather sections and blocks of css from the stylesheet (mainly classes related to the header and to this page) - didnt help.

Does anyone have any suggestions for anything else i can try?

Comment: Have you checked for any Javascript errors?

Comment: yes. no javascript errors.  And, the page actually slides up.  It just is not hitting the right target. :(

Comment: Have you fired up the debugger and stepped through each line to make sure that it's actually trying to go to the correct link?

Comment: yeah i did that. But wait guys, your not gonna believe this.  The browsers thought the targets were in the same place.  I inspected element on them and noticed that it kept showing it at the top of the page.  So, i added a class to those links and added display:block; clear:both; - Problem solved!  AAaarrrgh!

Comment: Try it in another browser and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried IE11, it did the same thing before.  Thanks guys for your time, but i fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Here is the solution if by some chances someone else has this same problem.

Add a class to your anchor targets

```
<a class="anchors" name="someanchor"></a>
```

The CSS for the anchor class needed this:

```
a.anchors, a.anchors:link { display:block; clear:both;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the selector you have chosen `a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` seems contradictory.

Have you tried something like:
 `$('#opt1, #opt2, #opt3, #opt4' ).click(function() {
// your code.
});`

???

Comment: That wasnt the problem.  I was targeting the links correctly.  When i clicked the anchor link, it would slide up - so targeting the links was not the problem.  Thanks for the reply, but i have now fixed it.